# Angular6: Performance with change cycles

Tags: angular, performance, angular6

I have a web application, written in Angular6. Everything works correctly, but I am curious whether I can optimise the performance of it. In my HTML bindings, I sometimes use a function call, for example in the `mat-paginator`, I use `getDataSize()`, and for some values, I use `{{getValueOfEntity(...)}}`.

Whenever I put a console.log in these methods, and open the console, I start getting infinite logs. I was wondering if this is normal, and if it downgrades the performance, since the function gets called constantly.

Do you have any idea if this is a serious problem, for example, Angular has to update the DOM constantly because of this or not? And if yes, is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: I'm having trouble to memoize my pipe. This is my current pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: "attributevalue",
  pure: true,
})
export class AttributeValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

public transform(element: Entity, attribute: AttributeType | "DEFAULT"): string {
    return this.getAttributeValue(element, attribute);
}

public getAttributeValue(element: Entity, attribute: AttributeType | "DEFAULT") {
    if (attribute === "DEFAULT") {
        return "Error: Attribute is 'DEFAULT'";
    } else {
        for (const attr of element.attributeAssignments) {
            if (attr.typeId === attribute.id) {
                return attr.value;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }
}
}
```

Any idea how to put in the memoize part?

Is it as simple as this? I have no idea to test if it works correctly:

```
const memoize = require("lodash.memoize");
return memoize(this.getAttributeValue(element, attribute));
```

in the transform function?

Comment: Every time the change detection is run, that function will be called. Instead it;s better to call the function once (in `ngOnInit` for example), store the result in a variable, and bind to that variable instead

Comment: You can also consider using angular pipe. which will cache the result based on input parameters.

Comment: @user184994 So I'll make variable out of the `groupByMode`, `totalDataSize` etc. When they don't change, that's very nice, and otherwise change them in another function.

Comment: Yep, that's should work

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya I took a moment to read up on pure pipes, and like you said, I should consider using them. `getValueOfEntity()` should always return the same value for an attribute of an entity, so this is a pure function I believe. I shall try and make a pipe for these sort of functions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding to a function you should try using a getter method. So for example:

```
getMyValue() { return 5 }
```

becomes

```
get myValue() { return 5 }
```

and in the HTML change your binding from `getMyValue()` to `myValue`

See if that reduces the number of calls.

In reference to the use of pure functions you might want to consider using lodash memoize. The first time the function is called it will process it, the second time - if the input is the same - it will return the already known output without processing.

EDIT RE: memoization

Not sure if pure pipes are already memoized behind the scenes.
One way to check is to see if the processing code is executed more than once for the same inputs.

If they are then you can do this:

```
const myMemoFunc = _.memoize(function myFunc(element, attribute) {
  if (attribute === "DEFAULT") {
    return "Error: Attribute is 'DEFAULT'";
  } else {
    for (const attr of element.attributeAssignments) {
      if (attr.typeId === attribute.id) {
        return attr.value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  } 
})

return myMemoFunc(element, attribute)
```

something along those lines :)

Comment: Funny how I was just reading an article talking about memoize ([This one](https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/11/12/faster-angular-applications-pure-pipes-memoization-pure-functions-part-2/) to be exact).

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to change the "change detection strategy" to OnPush.

```
@Component({
    selector: '..',
    templateUrl: '...',
    styleUrls: ['...'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

In this case, your component will update bindings only when `@Input` bindings will be updated.

But, keep in mind: when you change array or object, you have to create new instance for updating `@Input` every time when you change data inside array or object. Change detection will compare such types by link not value.

Or you can update it manually, for example after response from server:
inject into constructor `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` and call that whenever you need to update view `this.cdr.markForCheck();`

Comment: I've read about that a lot, but whenever I make use of the `OnPush` strategy, my page doesn't view correctly at the first time. My datatable isn't filled with entities and the selected attributes aren't set